# Cant get Steam API to show avatar upon Login

Tags: php, html, api, steam, avatar

I have used this tutorial to implement the steam login for a website I am creating: https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication/blob/f47fc78056081d6a83d277ae447c5386dc0909fc/README.md . Problem is, when I log in, it does not display any info, only a logout button. Here is the code I am dealing with.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['steamid'])){

    include("settings.php");
    if (empty($_SESSION['steam_uptodate']) or $_SESSION['steam_uptodate'] == false or empty($_SESSION['steam_personaname'])) {
        //We mute alerts from the following line because we do not want to give away our API key in case file_get_contents() throws a warning.
        @ $url = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$steamauth['apikey']."&steamids=".$_SESSION['steamid']);
        if($url === FALSE) { die('Error: failed to fetch content form Steam. It may be down. Please, try again later.'); }
        $content = json_decode($url, true);
        $_SESSION['steam_steamid'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['steamid'];
        $_SESSION['steam_communityvisibilitystate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['communityvisibilitystate'];
        $_SESSION['steam_profilestate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['profilestate'];
        $_SESSION['steam_personaname'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
        $_SESSION['steam_lastlogoff'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['lastlogoff'];
        $_SESSION['steam_profileurl'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['profileurl'];
        $_SESSION['steam_avatar'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatar'];
        $_SESSION['steam_avatarmedium'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatarmedium'];
        $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatarfull'];
        $_SESSION['steam_personastate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['personastate'];
        if (isset($content['response']['players'][0]['realname'])) { 
               $_SESSION['steam_realname'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['realname'];
           } else {
               $_SESSION['steam_realname'] = "Real name not given";
        }
        $_SESSION['steam_primaryclanid'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['primaryclanid'];
        $_SESSION['steam_timecreated'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['timecreated'];
        $_SESSION['steam_uptodate'] = true;
    }

    $steamprofile['steamid'] = $_SESSION['steam_steamid'];
    $steamprofile['communityvisibilitystate'] = $_SESSION['steam_communityvisibilitystate'];
    $steamprofile['profilestate'] = $_SESSION['steam_profilestate'];
    $steamprofile['personaname'] = $_SESSION['steam_personaname'];
    $steamprofile['lastlogoff'] = $_SESSION['steam_lastlogoff'];
    $steamprofile['profileurl'] = $_SESSION['steam_profileurl'];
    $steamprofile['avatar'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatar'];
    $steamprofile['avatarmedium'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatarmedium'];
    $steamprofile['avatarfull'] = $_SESSION['steam_avatarfull'];
    $steamprofile['personastate'] = $_SESSION['steam_personastate'];
    $steamprofile['realname'] = $_SESSION['steam_realname'];
    $steamprofile['primaryclanid'] = $_SESSION['steam_primaryclanid'];
    $steamprofile['timecreated'] = $_SESSION['steam_timecreated'];

}
```

What I want to happen is when someone logs in, where the sign in button was, I want to show the steam name as well as the avatar of whoever signed in.

Comment: You're not echoing or printing a single thing in your program.

Comment: About that line with `@`: If your users can see warnings output by PHP, exposing your API key should be the least of your worries.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the documentation? To show avatar, do the following:

```
$steamprofile['avatar'] //  32x32 version of avatar
$steamprofile['avatarmedium'] // 64x64 version of avatar
$steamprofile['avatarfull'] // 184x184 version of avatar
```

To display the Steam username, do the following:

```
$steamprofile['personaname']
```

It's all written in the `README.md` file at the bottom.

EDIT: If you want to show the image, do something like this:

```
echo '<img src="' . $steamprofile['avatar'] . '" />';
```

That will put the image URL from `$steamprofile['avatar']` into an `<img>` element.

Comment: I have a very basic knowledge of PHP, what I am confused about it where to put $steamprofile['avatar']

Comment: It will return an image URL. If you want to show the image, check my edit.